# Expanding UILabels inside custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an old iOS app written in objective c. It has several `UILabel`s that has given fixed x,y,width and height. Now what I want to do is when click on the `acessoryView` expand the cell and expand the `UILabel`s inside it. Also I want to change the positions of those UILabels. So far I have done cell expanding part in this way.

```
- (void)expandCell :(UIButton *)sender {
NSLog(@"NSINdex Path-------%li",(long)sender.tag);
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];
MetadataTableViewCell *cell = [_metadataListTVCTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0]];
if (newIndexPath == cellExpandedRow) {
    cell.isExpanded = true;
}
else {
    cell.isExpanded = false;
}

cellExpandedRow = newIndexPath;

[_metadataListTVCTableView beginUpdates];
[_metadataListTVCTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem: sender.tag inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[_metadataListTVCTableView endUpdates];
[_metadataListTVCTableView reloadData];
```

}

But I have no idea where I can do inner label frame updatings. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: if you set autolayout, then you only need to update the cellHeight delegate for expanded cells, then the label will auto expand.

Comment: @GeneCode without using auto layout is there any way you can suggest?

Comment: same way, you set the label frame in cellheight delegate
tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath.